# Update Java Bean every second

Tags: java, jsp, javabeans

### The Context

I have a jsp page including a table. The cell content of this table feeds from a bean which has a table attribute storing data. The data in the bean must randomly be changed every second, and the jsp must show the new data every time.

### The Problem

I have successfully linked the jsp page with the bean (the initial data appears in the web browser). What I have been unable to do is to change the data in the bean automatically every one second. From the readings I have done, threads seem to be illegal in beans.

How does one go about this? How do you update the bean every second?

Thanks!

Comment: Would the [PropertyChangeListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/beans/PropertyChangeListener.html) interface do what you're looking for?

Comment: This seems to only indicate when a bean property has been changed. I'm looking for a way to _change the bean automatically every second_.